# Want to make left and right trim on Java String

Tags: java

I have Java String which contain white space on both right and left side. I want to remove white space from both side.

Code that I tried...

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        String abc = "  Amebiasis  ";
        System.out.println(abc +" length "+abc.length());
        System.out.println(rtrim(abc)+" length "+rtrim(abc).length());
        System.out.println(ltrim(abc)+" length "+ltrim(abc).length());

        String ltrim = abc.replaceAll("^\\s+","");
        String rtrim = abc.replaceAll("\\s+$","");

        System.out.println("ltrim"+ltrim);
        System.out.println("rtrim"+rtrim);
    }

    public static String rtrim(String s) {
        int i = s.length()-1;
        while (i >= 0 && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
            i--;
        }
        return s.substring(0,i+1);
    }

    public static String ltrim(String s) {
        int i = 0;
        while (i < s.length() && Character.isWhitespace(s.charAt(i))) {
            System.out.println("s.charAt(i)  "+s.charAt(i));
            i++;
        }
        return s.substring(i);
    }
}
```

Output that I got...

```
  Amebiasis   length 13
  Amebiasis length 11
  Amebiasis   length 13
ltrim  Amebiasis  
rtrim  Amebiasis
```

Somehow it doesn't remove white space. What is wrong with my code, please help me on that.

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't just use the `trim` method that's already defined?

Comment: `@Dennis Meng` it also doesn't work..

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work", what exactly do you mean? What is the *output*?

Comment: `@jmort253'  "doesn't work",  means white space from side doesn't remove.

Comment: Actually, wait a sec. Is it important that you remove whitespace from only the left or only the right? If you want to remove whitespace from one side and not the other, then I agree, `trim` wouldn't be the right way to go.

Comment: You might want to show us exactly how you're using trim by posting an example. Right now, everyone is just sort of guessing, but no one has asked you to verify what you did that made trim not do what trim is designed to do. Hope this helps! :D

Comment: I don't get it, this code works fine for me as well as trim ._.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Defaultly available [trim()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#trim%28%29)

```
String abc = "  Amebiasis  ";
System.out.println(""+abc.trim());
```

Comment: I don't see how this is downvoted. Just run this test case: `public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {

String abc = "  Amebiasis  ";
System.out.println(">" + abc.trim() + "<");

}

}
` It clearly trims whitespace from both sides, just as the documentation says.  `javac Test.java` then `java Test` to compile and run, for the n00bs. :D)

Comment: Well, I guess I can speak for the downvoters. When you first posted this, there wasn't much here. It's correct, but I think you can add more to it, feel free to take the example from my comment. I'd also suggest citing the first sentence in the documentation for trim, just to solidify the point that trim *should* solve this problem. Hope this helps! :)

Comment: `@newuser` thanks for answer, i found problem that when i copied string from excel and doesn,t get trim using what i have done and as per your answer. it didn't got accurate answer that what is problem while copy string from excel, but i accept your answer. thanks

Comment: @Win i dont why. I am also did to read the excel sheet that having like this. Ask another question for this. you will surely get the answer

Comment: Yes, it will trim both the side

Answer (score 10):

I've tried both of your functions, `ltrim` and `rtrim` and they work fine. If I understand you correctly, you expect that these functions will change the content of string in place. It's impossible, because strings in Java are [immutable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object#Java). If you wish to trim whitespaces from your string and then proceed to work with trimmed version of the string, you need to assign the value that `rtrim` or `ltrim` returns to your `abc` variable:

```
String abc = "  Amebiasis  ";
abc = rtrim(abc); // abc now equals to "  Amebiasis"
abc = ltrim(abc); // abc now equals to "Amebiasis"
```

Comment: This answer makes a lot of sense! I think you might have solved the op's problem.

Comment: Excellent answer :) +1 for reminding us that strings in Java are immutable!

Answer (score 7):

Use regex to remove all spaces from both sides:

```
return str.replaceAll("\\s*$", "").replaceAll("^\\s*", "");
```

Comment: I won't downvote your answer but it's slower than the accepted one. Please rather use Pattern.compile("\\s*$").matcher(str).replaceAll("") instead of str.replaceAll(), store the patterns somewhere to avoid recompiling the both patterns at each call.

Answer (score 5):

Using the [Characters](https://github.com/kristian/characters) class, you can easily left / right trim any string for any given character(-class):

```
Characters.valueOf('x').trim( ... )
Characters.valueOf('x').leftTrim( ... )
Characters.valueOf('x').rightTrim( ... )
```

If you would like to trim for whitespaces, there is a predefined character-class available:

```
Characters.WHITESPACE.trim( ... )
Characters.WHITESPACE.leftTrim( ... )
Characters.WHITESPACE.rightTrim( ... )
```

The class does feature also other kinds of character operations, such `condense`, `replace` or `split`.

Comment: I've just looked at your source code, you recompile the pattern at each call, you shouldn't do that, it doesn't scale on hundreds of thousands strings.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is working, the output in your question is wrong, the real output of your code is:

```
  Amebiasis   length 13
  Amebiasis length 11
s.charAt(i)   
s.charAt(i)   
s.charAt(i)   
s.charAt(i)   
Amebiasis   length 11
ltrimAmebiasis  
rtrim  Amebiasis
```

If you only wish to trim both sides, just do

```
String abc = abc.trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to assign the trimmed string object to a new string because Strings are immutable and trim() cannot edit that String while having same address. So;

```
String abc = "  Amebiasis  ";
String abcTrimmed = abc.trim();
```

should work.

Answer (score -1):

You can simplify by using `\\S*`

Example:

```
String name = "Hello      ::    World";
abc.replaceAll("\\s*::\\s*", "");
```

output will be

```
HelloWorld
```